# Get JSON from server in asynctask and store in database

Tags: android, json, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am trying to build an android application which have user login system, which is done in AsyncTask. I have `UserLoginTask` which connects to web server and retrieves server response in String. This string should be parsed into local SQLite database and some fields should be in `SharedPreferences`. But the parsing of JSON is done when `doInBackground()` method finishes its work. The question is should I create another AsyncTask for parsing JSON and working with database for better performance? If yes, this AsyncTask (lets say ParseJSONtask) should be inside `LoginActivity` or `MainActivity` And when should I move from `LoginActivity` to `MainActivity`. And also what is the best practice for local user data storage system?

Comment: once you parse the data in doInBackground you can write things to database there itself.

Comment: Parse the JSON in your doInBackground. Put the data in your DB in the same doInBackground. No need to spread things out here.

Comment: @Knossos The server not always sends the same JSON. There is field status which indicates whether user login is successful or not. If yes, then there comes data lines

Comment: If you need to save to the DB, save to the DB in the same task (no need to split it up), if you don't need to save, don't.

Comment: So as I understood you suggest me parse this json immediately in the same task and only after this move to MainActivity?

Comment: @РагимРагимли, Search and combine two points, how to get son form server and how to store json object into database, hope it will make you clear

Comment: Your question is unclear and we all got downvotes for trying to answer it. Show examples of what you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use single AsyncTask to parse JSON response and store it to database. No need to create another AsyncTask for it. And when get correct response you should move from LoginActivity to MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 

    // get your response

    if ( response != null ) {

        // parse your response 

        // store data to database

        return true;    // if login success

    } else {

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);

   if ( result == true )

        Intent intent = new Intent( LoginActivity .this, MainActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {

        // if login failed then show meesage or do your stuff here

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

A good way to do it is using retrofit(http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

If you want to use just android, in doInBackground, you can take the json and parse it to the obj like in this tuto(http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can build your logic so that you do the downloading, parsing and saving all inside the same AsyncTask. You can of course start another AsyncTask if you really need. Nothing wrong with that approach other than your code getting messy.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use only one AsyncTask to parse and then store data, one by one.
2. You can have one AsyncTask for parsing, when parsing is done it calls a callback which starts another AsyncTask to handle the database. (Note: You can start that on a parallel executor. This will be faster since the storing will happen on parallel with the parsing. In your case this doesn't take a lot of time so it doesn't really matter)
3. Have only one AsyncTask which calls Volley first to get the data then parse and store.